# Passing a string parameter to another layout MvvmCross

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

So Basically I want to send a string parameter to another ViewModel but I keep getting null values back.

My FirstViewModel has this command to call the other layout with a string parameter

```
    public ICommand ReportCommand
    {
        get { return new MvxCommand(() => ShowViewModel<SecondViewModel>(new { param = "hello" })); }
    }
```

My Second ViewModel has

```
public void Init(string val)
{
    string a = val;
}
```

But I always get a null value for "val"

Any ideas why this is happening?

I also have an application output

```
mvx:Diagnostic: 62.54 Missing parameter for call to OverviewViewModel - missing parameter reportName - asssuming null - this may fail for value types!
mvx:Diagnostic: 62.54 Missing parameter for call to OverviewViewModel - missing parameter reportName - asssuming null - this may fail for value types!
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MvvmCross matches parameters by *name*. In your example, you should call:

```
ShowViewModel<SecondViewModel>(new { val = "hello" })
```

See sections 1. Construction and 2. Init() here:
https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/wiki/View-Model-Lifecycle